# Show only consistent records

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
item_number     item        owner_id       status
-----------     ----        --------       ------

12648        Powerbank        5569        returned
657891       Flash drive      5569        returned
6326         Wireless Mouse   5569        sold
987998       Pocket Wifi      8897        sold
78134        Wireless Mouse   7741        sold
7845159      Keyboard         1598        sold
87513        Monitor          1598        sold
9841523      Speakers         8965        returned
```

and I want the results to be like this:

```
item_number     item        owner_id       status
-----------     ----        --------       ------
987998       Pocket Wifi      8897        sold
78134        Wireless Mouse   7741        sold
7845159      Keyboard         1598        sold
87513        Monitor          1598        sold
```

So, basically, what I want is to extract the owners that had consistently sold items. Once a user had a returned item, then he shouldn't appear in the results.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the logic for `item_number` in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all rows for owners who never returned anything, then use `not exists` clause:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.owner_id = t.owner_id and t2.status <> 'sold'
                 );
```

If you just want a list of owners, then I would go with aggregation and a `having`:

```
select owner_id
from table t
group by owner_id
having sum(status <> 'sold') = 0;
```